# Jquery Remove closest li tag not working on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On click of a button I wanted to remove one of the `li` tag .

This is my HTML

```
<div class="inner-intit">
   <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub><br>
   <li vendor_id="1">
      <h6> vendor 1 at loc 1</h6>
      <p>Near Cyinet ,SoftSol , Hyderabad ,Telangana </p>
      <span class="inDeleteInnerSub"></span>
   </li>
   <input type="button" area="Madhapur" location="Office" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success buttonsearchRestaurant" value="Add Restaurant For  Office">
</div>
```

And i tried this way

```
$(document).on('click', '.inDeleteInnerSub', function(event ) {
    alert('sss');
if (confirm("Are You Sure Want to Delete Current Location?") == true) 
{
           var vendor_id = $(this).closest('li').attr('vendor_id');
    alert(vendor_id);
             $(this).closest('li').remove();
 }
});
```

But I don't know why its not removing the `li` tag. What could be causing this?

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3ubrtmk4/

Comment: your html is invalid... `li` can't be a child of `div`

Comment: `li` can only be child of `ul`, Change your HTML instead of `li` use `div`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out , so if li is child of div can't we remove the desired li??

Comment: which is the browser used to test it

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0fusjz3k/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. I have tested too.
CSS

```
 .inDeleteInnerSub{
        background:url(../images/icon-delete.png) center top no-repeat;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        opacity:0.5;
    }
    .inDeleteInnerSub:hover{
        opacity:0.8;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Jquery

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.inDeleteInnerSub', function(event ) {
      //  alert('sss');
    if (confirm("Are You Sure Want to Delete Current Location?") == true) 
    {
               var vendor_id = $(this).closest('li').attr('vendor_id');
                //alert(vendor_id);
               $(this).closest('li').remove();
     }
});

});
</script>
```

Html

```
<div class="inner-intit">
   <sub class="sub">Your Favorite Restaurant</sub><br>
   <li vendor_id="1">
      <h6> vendor 1 at loc 1</h6>
      <p>Near Cyinet ,SoftSol , Hyderabad ,Telangana </p>
      <div class="inDeleteInnerSub">Delete</div>
   </li>
   <input type="button" area="Madhapur" location="Office" name="btn1" class="btn btn-success buttonsearchRestaurant" value="Add Restaurant For  Office">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

span doesnot accept height and width hence your code works if you add some text to your span so that it has some height and width to click

```
<span class="inDeleteInnerSub">X</span>
```